# Efficiently find PIDs of many processes started by services

Tags: bash, centos7

I have a file with many **service** names, some of them are running, some of them aren't.

```
foo.service
bar.service
baz.service
```

I would like to find an efficient way to get the PIDs of the running processes started by the services (for the not running ones a 0, -1 or empty results are valid).

**Desired output example:**

```
foo.service:8484
bar.server:
baz.service:9447
```

(`bar.service` isn't running).

**So far I've managed to do the following: (1)**

```
cat t.txt | xargs -I {} systemctl status {} | grep 'Main PID' \
                                                | awk '{print $3}'
```

With the following output:

```
8484
9447
```

But I can't tell which service every PID belongs to.

(I'm not bound to use `xargs`, `grep` or `awk`.. just looking for the most efficient way).

**So far I've managed to do the following: (2)**

```
for f in `cat t.txt`; do
    v=`systemctl status $f | grep 'Main PID:'`;
    echo "$f:`echo $v | awk '{print \$3}'`";
done;
```

-- this gives me my desired result. Is it efficient enough?

Answer (score 32):

I ran into similar problem and fount leaner solution:

```
systemctl show --property MainPID --value $SERVICE
```

returns just the PID of the service, so your example can be simplified down to

```
for f in `cat t.txt`; do
    echo "$f:`systemctl show --property MainPID --value $f`";
done
```

Comment: Just for anyone wanting to try this top command, it seems that the correct syntax is `systemctl show --property MainPID value $SERVICE`

Comment: @AndyShearer if you use "value" instead of "--value", systemctl considers it a name of another service. "--value" in this case forces systemctl to output only value rather than "MainPID=1234" pair.

Comment: I didn't know that - thanks for the information. I thought that it was a typo, but good to know the difference between `value` and `--value`.

Comment: This `--value` flag has to be relatively new because systemd 219 which is the current default on CentOS 7 does not recognize this flag.

Comment: Judging by https://github.com/systemd/systemd/releases/tag/v219, systemd 219 came out in 2015 (and CentOS 7 in 2014), so it's quite possible it doesn't support that.
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/NEWS#L4449 - here they've added support for it in version 230.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
while read -r line; do
    statuspid="$(sudo service $line status | grep -oP '(?<=(process|pid)\s)[0-9]+')"

    appendline=""
    [[ -z $statuspid ]] && appendline="${line}:${statuspid}" || appendline="$line"

    "$appendline" >> services-pids.txt 
done < services.txt
```

To use within a variable, you could also have an associative array:

```
declare -A servicearray=()

while read -r line; do
    statuspid="$(sudo service $line status | grep -oP '(?<=(process|pid)\s)[0-9]+')"

    [[ -z $statuspid ]] && servicearray[$line]="statuspid"
done < services.txt

# Echo output of array to command line
for i in "${!servicearray[@]}"; do  # Iterating over the keys of the associative array
  # Note key-value syntax
  echo "service: $i | pid: ${servicearray[$i]}"
done
```

*Making it more efficient*:

To list all processes with their execution commands and PIDs. This may give us more than one PID per command, which might be useful:

```
ps -eo pid,comm
```

So:

```
psidcommand=$(ps -eo pid,comm)

while read -r line; do
    # Get all PIDs with the $line prefixed
    statuspids=$(echo $psidcommand | grep -oP '[0-9]+(?=\s$line)')

    # Note that ${statuspids// /,} replaces space with commas
    [[ -z $statuspids ]] && appendline="${line}:${statuspids// /,}" || appendline="$line"

    "$appendline" >> services-pids.txt 
done < services.txt
```

OUTPUT:

```
kworker:5,23,28,33,198,405,513,1247,21171,22004,23749,24055
```

If you're confident your file has the **full** name of the process, you can replace the:

```
grep -oP '[0-9]+(?=\s$line)'
```

with

```
grep -oP '[0-9]+(?=\s$line)$' # Note the extra "$" at the end of the regex
```

to make sure it's an exact match (in the `grep` without trailing `$`, line "mys" would match with "mysql"; in the `grep` *with* trailing `$`, it would not, and would only match "mysql").

Comment: So, performance-wise, doing `grep -oP ...` is more efficient than `systemctl status...`? The downside as you said is multiple PIDs....

Answer (score 0):

Building up on Yorik.sar's answer, you first want to get the `MainPID` of a server like so:

```
for SERVICE in ...<service names>...
do
    MAIN_PID=`systemctl show --property MainPID --value $SERVICE`
    if test ${MAIN_PID} != 0
    than
        ALL_PIDS=`pgrep -g $MAIN_PID`
        ...
    fi
done
```

So using `systemctl` gives you the PID of the main process controlled by your daemon. Then the `pgrep` gives you the daemon and a list of all the PIDs of the processes that daemon started.

**Note:** if the processes are user processes, you have to use the `--user` on the `systemctl` command line for things to work:

```
MAIN_PID=`systemctl --user show --property MainPID --value $SERVICE`
```

Now you have the data you are interested in the `MAIN_PID` and `ALL_PIDS` variables, so you can print the results like so:

```
if test -n "${ALL_PID}"
then
    echo "${SERVICE}: ${ALL_PIDS}"
fi
```